# RDP Access in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, sql, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to restrict RDP access the SQL server to be only from the Terminal Services server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the properties of the RDP in rules of the Windows firewall you can configure which hosts can access from the remote computers tab.

Comment: If I allow only a connection from a certain IP, how do I block the others?

Comment: If you only add one IP in the top box then that will be the only IP/hostname it accepts connections from.

Comment: How do you mean by top box

Comment: If you go to the Windows firewall from the control panel-> advanced settings-> inbound rules-> RDP (TCP and UDP two separate rules,)-> click on properties from the right hand column-> select the remote computers tab-> check the box (will warn you that connection needs to be secure (general tab)-> enter desired IP/hostname(s).